# AngularJS handle incoming HTTP calls from backend server

Tags: java, angularjs, http

currently I'm using AngularJS as my frontend framework for my website with a java backend server. The java server is running a task on a loop, and is constantly updating its information. In real time, I want to be able to display the changes in the data created by the backend server in my frontend Angular application.

From what I've read on various questions, Angular is NOT designed to handle incoming HTTP requests, and instead only to be used to make calls to the backend server. But, for the scenario that I'm presenting, it makes more sense for the backend server to push the changes its made to the data right to the Angular frontend instead of waiting for Angular to make a call to the server for data.

What's the best way to achieve this type of frontend/backend relationship between Angular and a java backend server?

Comment: A browser does not accept "incoming" HTTP requests, as you put it. There are a couple of ways to achieve what you are looking for, the newest and most common being WebSockets. However, be aware that not all browsers have full WebSocket support, so you may have to use alternatives like Long-Polling.

Comment: More specifically, you might be interested in this: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket

Comment: Alright, I'll check it out. Thanks for the reply.